# Ethernet connection drops after several seconds

Tags: networking, power, ethernet, dhcp

I recently got a Raspberry Pi, but I've been having trouble getting a working internet connection.

At the moment, the pi will connect, and I'll be able to access the internet for about 15 seconds until it suddenly disconnects (it disappears from the list of DHCP devices on my router). I then have to use `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` to reconnect, which either causes the graphics to freeze or lets the Pi access the internet for another 15 seconds or so. When the GUI (startx) isn't running, and I'm just using `ping 8.8.8.8` the connection doesn't seem to drop.

It's running Raspbian, the power cable is 5V and 0.7A and the eth0 interface is using DHCP. I can provide any other information which might help to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using USB peripherals?

I don't know if you have a good quality power supply. Consider that 700mA is the minimum required... You can try with a ~1A supply.

Comment: Currently just a mouse and (Logitech) keyboard, with a combined power consumption of 750mW. I'll try and find a different adapter and see if that helps.

Comment: I found a 2A charger and it worked perfectly! Thank you Emanuele!

Comment: And my Ethernet drops together with 3G dongle, and my power supply is 2A. Could it be insufficient?